# Websphere admin console: Disable redirect from http to https

Tags: ssl, websphere, websphere-8

In IBM Websphere(8.5.5.14) wehen we access the adming console using the insecure url

http://[server]:9060/ibm/console, we are redirected to https://[server]:9043/ibm/console

How to disable such a redirect and how to be able to use the admin console in an insecure way ?

This is generally not preferred, but what I have is a Websphere running under kubernetes and the routes already take care of ssl so internally within the cluster, I don't require ssl.

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Comment: No. I was not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to disable ssl for the admin console when security is enabled.  The unsecure port can only be accessed when global security is disabled.

Comment: I don't want to disable ssl on port 9043 or disable that port. Only if the redirect from insecure port (9060) could be disabled, it would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to do this without disabling Administrative Security entirely, which would also allow anyone in, without authentication.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/csec_global.html

> Administrative security can be thought of as a "big switch" that
>   activates a wide variety of security settings for WebSphere®
>   Application Server. Values for these settings can be specified, but
>   they will not take effect until administrative security is activated.
>   The settings include the authentication of users, the use of Secure
>   Sockets Layer (SSL), and the choice of user account repository. In
>   particular, application security, including authentication and
>   role-based authorization, is not enforced unless administrative
>   security is active. Administrative security is enabled by default.

Comment: I hope there is a way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

This could be happening because authentication is on for your Websphere admin console, so redirect to https is default set on when admin console is accessed. If the security is disabled, the admin console can be accessed from http. It can done from wsadmin in cmd with these steps

```
1. <WAS_INSTALL_DIR>/bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE
2. wsadmin> securityoff
3. wsadmin> exit
4. Restart the servers (running Java processes should be stopped)
```

More details here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/disabling-websphere-administrative-security-when-admin-console-not-accessible

Comment: grindlewald, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)